# Metaphors and analogies used by physicists and science communicators in history?

Tags: physics

What are some famous and brilliant metaphors and analogies used by physicists and science writers and communicators to explain complex physical ideas?

Comment: I think such an extremely open-ended question is probably not such a great fit for the SE model.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you include physicists dabbling in mathematics in the scope of your question, I would mention that Leibniz used the comparison of a grain of sand and the Earth to motivate his notion of an infinitesimal number.  He also compared distances on Earth with distances to the Heavens to give an idea of an infinite number.